# PHP:Query not returning all db results but instead duplicating

Tags: php, mysqli

Yesterday i posted a question regarding my query not working as i wanted it to ([question can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367461/select-data-from-db-based-on-user-input)), I now have a small problem which i have been working on all night regarding the same query. However, now it is working somewhat better as it is only showing the categories needed.

I have a search bar, which directs the user to another page to show the products they have searched for on the first page. My website allows users to search for takeaways in their area. On the second page i have a drop down list, this is used to search through the different food categories for that area.

I have 30 food categories, and the query now only shows food categories the area has and does not show all the others (which it didn't before). My problem now is for example a certain postcode has 3 takeaways under the same category 3 takeaways will show, but all 3 takeaways will be the same takeaways instead of the 3 different takeaways.

I have changed my query from SELECT * to SELECT DISTINCT. I have also added $i=1/$i++ above and below my while statement in order to try and retrieve the information required, however no luck.

These are the 3 tables i am using:

```
Delivery_Pcode Tbl
1   Del_code_id
2   Restaurant_ID
3   Pcode   
4   Del_Price


Rest_Category tbl
1   CategoryID
2   Cuisine_category
3   Category_img

Rest_Details Tel
1   Resturant_ID
2   Resturant_name
3   City_name
4   Cat_ID
```

**Query**

```
    $get_cats = "SELECT DISTINCT 
    Rest_Details.Resturant_ID,
    Rest_Details.Cat_ID,
    Rest_Details.Resturant_ID,
    Rest_Category.CategoryID,
    Rest_Category.CategoryID,
    Rest_Category.Cuisine_category,
    Delivery_Pcode.Pcode 

   FROM Rest_Category
   INNER JOIN Rest_Details
   ON Rest_Category.CategoryID = Rest_Details.Cat_ID
   INNER JOIN Delivery_Pcode
   ON Delivery_Pcode.Restaurant_ID = Rest_Details.Resturant_ID
   WHERE Rest_Details.Resturant_ID = '" . $rest_id ."' AND 
   Delivery_Pcode.Pcode= '" . $searchq ."';";


  $run_cats = mysqli_query($dbc, $get_cats);

  if (!$get_cats) {
  echo "Oops: Its seems like we have a problem, refresh and try again";
  } else {

  $i=1;
  while ($row_cats = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)) {

  $CategoryID = $row_cats['CategoryID'];
  $Cuisine_category = $row_cats['Cuisine_category'];

  echo"<option value=' $CategoryID'>$Cuisine_category$i</option>";

                    }

                 $i++;
     }
```

Preview of date in db

**Rest details**

[image]

**Rest_Category**

[image]

**Delivery_code**

[image]

**This is what i get**

[image]

This is the result i get when clicking on american. But as you can see from the data in the rest_details and rest_category tbl, american category is assignment to both McDonalds and KFC, so two McDonalds shouldn't be showing. It could be McDonalds and KFC like below.

[image]

Comment: haha *"Oops: Its seems like we have a problem, refresh and try again"* = If your car breaks down, try getting out of it and then getting back in.

Comment: What is `$i` for? The incrementation is outside the loop so it will always be 1.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of data in your tables. The output your query gives now and the expected result? Better through http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @chris85 sorry internet went down. So i need to put it directly under the echo "</option..

Comment: @user4035 i will do that just now give me 2 minutes

Comment: @user4035 took longer then i thought to prepare

Comment: @user6362696 Thank you. Let me look.

Comment: @user6362696 Can you give an example of your query: what do you get, and what do you want to get?

Comment: @user4035 i will screen print my results and add it into the question give me 5 minutes

Comment: @user4035 I've added

Comment: @user6362696 Where do you get `$rest_id` and `$searchq` variables?